# stop my app in android studio When I added second activity

Tags: android

in my app when you click on image it will move you to another layout
but the problem is

since I added the SecondActivity and put some methods there, a message come "Unfortunately my app has stooped"
I know there are many questions similar this but unfortunately it dose not work with me.

This is the MainActivity

```
    package com.Anwaar.Hashem;

    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
   import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
   import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
   import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.view.ViewStub;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import android.app.Activity;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



private ViewStub stubGrid;
private ViewStub stubList;
private ListView listView;
private GridView gridView;
public ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
public GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;
private List<Product> productList;
private int currentViewMode = 0;

static final int VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW = 0;
static final int VIEW_MODE_GRIDVIEW = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    stubList = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_list);
    stubGrid = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_grid);

    //Inflate ViewStub before get view

    stubList.inflate();
    stubGrid.inflate();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGridView);

    //get list of product
    getProductList();
    gridView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    //Get current view mode in share reference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ViewMode", 
 MODE_PRIVATE);
    currentViewMode = sharedPreferences.getInt("currentViewMode", 
 VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW);//Default is view listview
    //Register item lick
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick);

    switchView();




    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
 R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
 findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



private void switchView() {

    if(VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW == currentViewMode) {
        //Display listview
        stubList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Hide gridview
        stubGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        //Hide listview
        stubList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Display gridview
        stubGrid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    setAdapters();
 }


private void setAdapters() {
    if(VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW == currentViewMode) {
        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, 
 productList);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    } else {
        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item, 
 productList);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }
}

public List<Product> getProductList() {
    //pseudo code to get product, replace your code to get real product here
    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.ii1, " Story Name", "This is 
 description 1"));
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i2, "Story Name", "This is 
 description 2"));
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i3, "Story Name", "This is 
 description 3"));
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i4, "Story Name", "This is 
 description 4"));
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i5, "Story Name", "This is 
 description 5"));
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i6, "Story Name", "This is description 
6"));

    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i8, "Story Name", "This is 
  description 8"));
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i9, "Story Name", "This is 
  description 9"));
    productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i10, "Story Name", "This is 
  description 10"));

    return productList;
 }

  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClick = new 
  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
    long id) {
        //Do any thing when user click to item
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
   productList.get(position).getTitle() + " - "
                + productList.get(position).getDescription(), 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
  };





 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
  } 



 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

 }

 public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
  }



  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            if(VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW == currentViewMode) {
                currentViewMode = VIEW_MODE_GRIDVIEW;
            } else {
                currentViewMode = VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW;
            }
            //Switch view
            switchView();
            //Save view mode in share reference
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
            getSharedPreferences("ViewMode", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("currentViewMode", currentViewMode);
            editor.commit();

            break;
    }
    return true;
  }



 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
  }
```

This is the SecondActivity

```
     package com.Anwaar.Hashem;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
 public class SecondActivity extends Activity  {

Toolbar mToolbar;
ImageView sample;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    sample  = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        mToolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("title"));

        if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.ii1));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")){
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i2));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i3));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i4));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i5));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i6));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i8));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i9));

        }

        else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
            sample .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i10));

        }


    }
}

 }
```

This is The manifests

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Anwaar.Hashem">

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.Anwaar.Hashem.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.Anwaar.Hashem.SecondActivity">
         </activity>



</application>

 </manifest>
```

also I have GridViewAdapter, ListViewAdapter, and Product java files

Comment: please share error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);`

This is the error. You should never do this. If you are doing this that means that you are changing the layout content of the first Activity to that of the second activity, but that's not what you want to do. You want to change the activity.

When you go to a new activity it calls the `onCreate()` method where the content view is initialized. Once that is done you shouldn't change that untill absolutely necessary.

If you just write this, 
`Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);`   it will work perfectly.

Comment: oh thanks for this information, I fixed it.
but the problem still there

this is the Error found in  my Logcat can you see it, if it is possible

Comment: Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you start the second activity, you should not set content view in first

```
public void onClick(View v){
Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
/*---------- setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);---*/
```

}

Also I think you should move this code to `onItemClick()` method of your class

This line is causing the problem.
`gridView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);`

remove that line

and replace this `gridView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick);` with

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for this information, I fixed it.
but the problem still there my app  still stopped >_<

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: when i replaced my code with your code it is work thanks  but when i click on image it is freeze

Comment: i do not know how can i post  code on comment